# Reflecting a ray (of light) in bge?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm working toward a system where the player can bounce a ray around toward a target using mirror objects. Essential to this process will be making the ray reflect properly. 
Essentially, I thought it would be best if I simply added an object at the ray hitPosition that would emit a new ray. This adds the object, but not in the right orientation. Is there a way I can have the game engine calculate which way the new object should face?

I want to make the new ray reflect at a equal angle (when bisected by a perpendicular of the mirror face) to the angle that the ray came in on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this, and .rayCast() should set you right

vector.reflect(hitNormal)
http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/GameModule/MathutilsModule_5_4.html